# Declare a dynamic constant in Maxima

Tags: math, constants, maxima, declare

I need to declare a variable as constant, the variable is generated while the program is running, I tried this way:

```
foo(var) := declare(''var, constant)$

foo(x)$

facts();
```

But that doesn't work and I get:

```
[kind(var, constant)]
```

everytime.

instead:

```
[kind(x, constant)]
```

When I write code without a function, everything works fine:

```
var: x$

declare(''var, constant)$

facts();
```

I get:

```
[kind(x, constant)]
```

Does anyone know how to **do this dynamically via a function**?

Comment: function: eval_string (str) helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional way to ensure that arguments are evaluated, even for functions which otherwise quote their arguments, is to `apply` the function to the arguments. E.g.:

```
apply (declare, [var, 'constant]);
```

Or, in a function:

```
foo(var) := apply (declare, [var, 'constant]);
```

`apply` evaluates its arguments, so the arguments are evaluated by the time the function sees them.

The quote-quote `''var` doesn't have the expected effect in a function because quote-quote is applied only at the time the expression is parsed. So any later assignment to `var` has no effect.

I recommend against `eval_string`. There is almost always a better way to do anything than string processing; in this case that better way is `apply`.